# How get get a list of @ mention tag IDs from raw syntax in a video game app?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making a video game app that lets users @ mention a game stored in the database, similar to the way you can @ mention a user on Twitter, or @ mention anything on Facebook.

When the user types '@' when making a comment, JavaScript triggers a drop-down box to appear. The user selects a game from the drop-down box and when he selects it, it goes into the textarea. Each @ mention is stored internally in format @[id-slug:Game Title]. When the user presses "Post", the comment is sent to the server, and the server must process it, to figure out which games were being @ mentioned. An example of the raw text sent to the server would be:

`@[6816-nes-super-mario-bros:Super Mario Bros.] is a great game! @[6821-nes-super-mario-bros-3:Super Mario Bros. 3] is fun too!`

The server must be able to know which games the user is @ mentioning in his post, so that it can add entries to the `comment_game` table appropiately, so that these comments also show up on the respective game pages. So in the example above, I need some way to parse this comment to figure out that the user has @ mentioned game IDs 6816 and 6821. Just getting the game IDs will be sufficient for this. Then PHP can know what games the user @ mentioned.

I have tried multiple solutions but none seem to work. I'm not sure if the best solution is to use regular expressions, or another solution.

Comment: regex will work fine to pull all the ids, you should just learn how to use it. your previous [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290907/how-to-convert-mention-syntax-to-html-in-a-video-game-app/26291040#26291040) was correct and all you have to do is modify the regex a bit for your updated string format. on the frontend using javascript this will get and array of ids `var arr = yourstring.match(/@\[(\d*)/g);`

Comment: match seems to be including the first part as well and not getting just the capturing group of digits, but with the same regex this will work to get an array of ids that are inside the capturing group, `var matches = [];
str.replace(/@\[(\d*)/g, function(m, p1){ matches.push(p1); } );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $comment = '@[6816-nes-super-mario-bros:Super Mario Bros.] is a great game! @[6821-nes-super-mario-bros-3:Super Mario Bros. 3] is fun too!';
    preg_match_all('/@\[([0-9]+)/', $comment, $users);
    print_r($users);
?>
```

Comment: Strange, this returns `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @[6816
            [1] => @[6821
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6816
            [1] => 6821
        )

)
`
The information in array index 0 ("@[6816" and "@[6821") is unneeded, though the 2 IDs in array index 1 is exactly what I need.